# MS Excel VBA - Copying SpecialCells while keeping the destination formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy these special cells to a destination, while keeping the destination's formatting. I'm thinking I have to put .values somewhere in the lines. The code is as follows:

```
GRBReportSheet.Range("C" & GRBReportSheetFR & ":E" & GRBReportSheetLR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=GRB.Range("C30")
GRBReportSheet.Range("F" & GRBReportSheetFR & ":J" & GRBReportSheetLR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=GRB.Range("H30")
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
GRBReportSheet.Range("C" & GRBReportSheetFR & ":E" & GRBReportSheetLR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
GRB.Range("C30").PasteSpecial xlValues

GRBReportSheet.Range("F" & GRBReportSheetFR & ":J" & GRBReportSheetLR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
GRB.Range("H30").PasteSpecial xlValues
```